# Discourse Installation procedure in bluehost

Tags: discourse

How to install discourse in Blue host with the code from Github ?
I have blue host web hosting i want to know the steps to host discourse for my own domain using bluehost hosting service.

Comment: What did you try? What is the problem?

Comment: it didn't try yet. i am new ruby on rails, i wanted to know the installation procedure in order to proceed.

Comment: Pleas read [ask]. SO isn't a handholding website. SO is a website for answering *specific* programming problems.